# Select/Copy Plotly Hovertext

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Is there a way to lock hovertext in place when I click a datapoint? I would like to be able to click and HTML hyperlink in the text, or copy a key from the text into another system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a possibility for that, I doubt it.

If you are trying do develop an Dashboard or anything like that, you could create a div depending on a "click_event".

You could check [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R7VMSLwooo), maybe it helps. The final result is shown at minute 31:22.